# How to blur Selectize.js input after selection has been made in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I am using the Selectize.js. From the docs it says I can set up a 'onDropdownClose' callback here: [Selectize docs](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md).  I can't seem to get it to work.

How do I blur (defocus) the input after a selection has been made using Selectize.js?  All the blurs in the below code do not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myinput").selectize({
    onDropdownClose : function ($dropdown) {
                       $($dropdown).prev().find('input').blur();
                      }
    });
});
```

EDIT:
I am using Bootstrap 3.1.1.  I just noticed that the default behavior for Bootstrap 2 is to blur the input after a selection has been made while Bootstrap 3+ leaves the input in focus after a selection has been made.  My question still stands for Bootstrap 3+

Edit:
I got it to work with the above code.

Comment: Were you unable to just do:
`$dropdown.blur();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding this just to have an actual answer. Your solution works.

```
$("#myinput").selectize({
  onDropdownClose: function(dropdown) {
    $(dropdown).prev().find('input').blur();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and solved it using:

```
$('#myinput').selectize({
    onItemAdd: function () {
        this.blur();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can access input field like this:

```
$("#myinput").selectize({
    onDropdownClose: function(dropdown) {
        this.$control_input.blur();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`closeAfterSelect` option has been added since 0.12.0.

https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/v0.12.0/docs/usage.md#options

Answer (score 0):

Accepted (deadwards) answer was fine, but in situation like this:
you open the menu, and close it by clicking back on the input element. In this situation, the dropdownmenu gets opened again.
I used this variant. I know, it is an ugly solution, but it worked better in this situation. You could change timout delay to fit your situation bettter, this was fine for me.

```
        onDropdownClose: function (dropdown) {
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                self.$control_input.blur();
            }, 250);
        }
```